# Android ViewModel slow navigation on already loaded data

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Im working on loading data from Firebase Realtime Database by ViewModel. In my layout I have progress bar and recyclerview. Things work perfecly when i need to load my data first, when I click on button fragment opens instantly, progress bar is running and when data loads it stop running and recyclerview shows up. But, when i go into that fragment again (Data is already loaded), no progress bar is shown (which is okay), but it takes about second to comming that switch, which is significantly slower than first behaviour that i described.

So, I am wondering what is making it to wait that long in second scenario and how can I override it, so my fragment shows up first and then shows up recyclerview?

I have already tried using viewstub and dummy views but nothing seems to work..

My **CategoryFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MenuViewModel.class);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    if(root == null || fragmentState == STATE_STARTUP)
    {
        binding = FragmentCategoryRecyclerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        root = binding.getRoot();

        binding.categoryRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.categoryRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.layout_item_fade_scale);

        myFoodListAdapter = new MyFoodListAdapter(getContext(), foodModelList, String.valueOf(menuIndex), String.valueOf(categoryIndex));
        binding.categoryRecycler.setAdapter(myFoodListAdapter);
    }
    else
        binding = FragmentCategoryRecyclerBinding.bind(root);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel.getMessageError().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

    homeViewModel.getMenuList(restaurantId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), menuModels -> {
        if(fragmentState == STATE_STARTUP || fragmentState == STATE_SEARCHING)
        {
            binding.categoryRecycler.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
            myFoodListAdapter.setFoodModelList(menuModels.get(menuIndex).getCategories().get(categoryIndex).getItems());
            binding.progressBar.hide();
            binding.categoryRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fragmentState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
            if(foodModelList.isEmpty())
                foodModelList = menuModels.get(menuIndex).getCategories().get(categoryIndex).getItems();
            myFoodListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    binding = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply
Use viewmodel or androidviewmodel in onstart instead on create